# smooth out/filter matrix data

Tags: matlab, matrix, filter, filtering

I've got a 25x10 matrix that shows a fairly rough surface when i plot it.
I'd like to filter it out to create a smooth surface with more datapoints for a finer grid(but not lineary interpolated), and i need the filtered data that produces the smoothed surface as base for an open-loop. Can anyone recommend me a good approach? The result right now looks like this:

[image: surface]
Cheers

EDIT: griddata with method 'cubic' looks more like the desired result, but it's still holding onto the data too much. The image below visualizes the result with cubic, and the desired result. The goal is to see no more clear peaks in the surface.

[image: Desired result]

Comment: Why not using a non-linear interpolation ? You can use `interpn` with the method `spline` or `cubic`

Answer (score 1):

Use `griddata` to interpolate your data over a finer mesh. If x, y and z is your data, you can define a fine mesh (xq, yq) and interpolate / extrapolate your data on that extend. Since the default method is 'linear' and because you want to make your surface profile smoother, you should specify another method, like 'natural'.

```
[xq, yq] = meshgrid(0:20:6000, 0.2:0.01:1);
zq = griddata(x(:), y(:), z(:), xq, yq, 'natural');
surf(xq, yq, zq, 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how do i use griddata with a matrix? I dont have x,y, and z values.

Comment: Your plot does not seem like having arbitrary values for x and y. How do you have your data and how do you plot it? Anyway, if you do not have x and y anywhere you can make them also with `meshgrid`, but in a way that the size of x and y is as your z (25x10). For example `[x,y] = meshgrid(240:240:6000, 0.1:0.1:1)`. Then you will have 3 matrices with the same size and the code above will be fine then.

Comment: i planned to specify the x and y values later, as the shape and data of the matrix is of main priority, so i can use any x and y values i want for now. I have used the meshgrid to create two values to use as you adviced, but the entire matrix is filled with NaNs now, i suppose the cause lies in the zq and yq values, what would i have to do with those?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. What is the situation now? Any progress? Which matrix is filled with NaN? Would be nice to write some of your code.

Comment: I have filled the NaN values, but i haven't achieved any smoothing yet. i'm not really sure what to fill in for xq and yq. I have used the ranges that my x and y values span, but i think that's not right. The surface plot i get now looks exactly like the unsmoothed one. I've used 'natural' like you mentioned. i'll post the code in my question.

Comment: For `xq` and `yq` you should use a mesh with higher resolution than your data, if you want to interpolate. Try this instead and you will see what I mean: `[xq, yq] = meshgrid(0.2:0.01:1.1, 1200:20:6000)`

Comment: thx I did as you said and it worked, but the result was a surface filled with 'cliff' like peaks all over the surface. the cubic method gave a much better result though, but its still holding on to my data too much. ie. i can still see (smoothed)peaks everywhere, while i'd want them smoothed out much much more. It doesn't have to use the actual data i have, because there's outliers and peaks in it everywhere. it has to plot a nice smooth surface between the peaks and outliers. griddata doesn't have a smoothing factor though, so i'm trying it with 'gridfit' now.(downloaded script)

Comment: to clarify my comment, i also tried to use interpn with cubic, which holds on to the data and interpolates between the points. This seems to do the same as griddata, while the best would be if it estimates a very smooth surface by using the data i supply. It's like scattered data, where you draw a smooth line between a lot of points, while not actually come accross every one of them. I posted a visual clarification of my question in an update.